# loading package throws exception

Tags: flutter

i am using the loading package to show a loading screen while fetching some data. It seems to work well, but i see the following error in my console:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 671 pos 7: '_ticker != null': AnimationController.animateWith() called after AnimationController.dispose()
```

AnimationController methods should not be used after calling dispose.

```
  Widget getLoadingBar() {
    return new Container(

      color: Colors.blue
      child: Center(
        child: Loading(indicator: BallPulseIndicator(), size: 100.0),
      ),
    );
  }
return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: new LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.yellow,    Colors.blue, Colors.red, Colors.yellow], begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter, tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
                ),
                child: dataFetched ? getContent() : getLoadingBar(),
            )
        ),
      );
```

When the async fetch is finished the dataFetched bool is set to true inside a setState call.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1.you have to dispose your AnimationController or any other controller.

```
void dispose(){
  _animationController.dispose(); 
}
```

2.if you call setState in your program then wrap that like this.

```
 if(this.mounted){
   setState((){
      // your code .....
   });
```

Comment: 1. i dont have a reference to the animationController used in the loading package. 2. can you explain why i should wrap the setState call?

Comment: when project build it generated widget tree and assign mounted to true for every widget if widget is not a part of tree then unmounted that widget so it's good to check that that widget is part of widget or not .  you can check https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/     https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html